# DocuSign error in getting the production accounts for the user when promote a key to production

Tags: docusignapi

I followed the steps to go-live the integration key. I made 20 successful API calls and passed the review. So I proceeded to 'Select Go-live account' to promote the key to production. In the login page, I logged in to the production account that I want to use for managing the production key, however, after I authenticated, I got an error message 'Error in getting the production account for the user. Please try again sometime.'

The developer account has the admin permission, the production account also has the admin permission. Any thoughts why did I get this issue?

Comment: Do you use SSO?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently a bug related to using SSO (Single Sign-On) for production account that is being promoted to with [Go-Live](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/).

The workaround you can use for now until the bug is fixed:

1: Disable SSO on the user you're trying to promote with in their production account

2: Try and promote the key again with SSO disabled. The key should promote if it's related to the bug

3: You can then re enable SSO

Comment: Yes, it is the SSO bug. We disabled SSO and we were able to promote the key.

Comment: The good news is, the Go-Live SSO issue is currently being worked (Tracked internally as DCM-9457). In the mean time, temporarily setting a Login Policy Exception for the admin who will be promoting the ikey should allow that to go through: https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/How-to-exclude-specific-users-from-SSO-requirements?language=en_US&rsc_301

Comment: I had to deal with this bug as well.  In the demo environment after clicking to promote the API key - in the little window I had to use my production environment credentials directly NOT through our SSO system.  I hope this gets fix soon.

Comment: We encountered this as well today, and it's shameful, insane, and pathetic that DocuSign hasn't fix this bug after 4+ months.